# Mac: stream a video file as webcam to applications (similar to CamTwist)

Tags: macos, video-streaming, desktop-application, webcam, broadcast

I am trying to program a feature, similar to that of CamTwist, with which a video file (on hard disk) can be broadcasted to other applications as video input.

However, I am not sure where to begin..googling did not help much either.

a little guidance could be useful. :)

Comment: So which of the two possible uses are you targeting? Faking a "live cam" porn site or cheating at Chat Roulette? ;-)

Comment: LMAO :D ..well as of this moment..2nd is much closer!

Answer (score 1):

You've got the OSX tag set so I'm guessing you want to do this on a Mac.  Take a look at [Syphon](http://syphon.v002.info/) it has a good shot at being what you're looking for.